# Blue Prism - How filter a collection using NOT operator

Tags: excel, filter, collections, rpa, blueprism

I need to filter a collection that have "HoldingSubholding" column, that can have lot of different value. I need All the rows with the values except the rows that have value "A".

How can I filter the collection?
I would like to use EQUAL NOT, how could i write that?

"HoldingSubholding **=NOT** 'A'"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkuy3.png)

Comment: So use A1<>B1, that is not equal to.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's a VBO from the digital exchange, utility-collection manipulation. It has an action called filter collection- Input the collection and the filter expression "HoldingSubholding <> 'A'"

Or you can use a loop stage to loop through the collection, and a decision stage to check the condition [Collection.HoldingSubholding] <> "A"

Answer (score 0):

“[Column Name] <>’A’”

<> is exact opposite of = which allows you to deselect or filter out non relevant Data in columns.